# What's the difference between registering a service worker within a popup.html and utilizing a chrome extension's manifest.json v3 service-worker.js?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In the Chrome extension, I can make a popup.html and register a service worker as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('path/to/my/service-worker.js', {
        scope: '/my-scope',
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, after the release of manifest.json V3, you may explicitly specify the service-worker file to execute as follows:

```json
{
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "sw.js"
  }
}
```

What's the distinction between these two?

What happens if I register the same service-worker in both of these methods?

Comment: Browser does it automatically so there's no need to do it manually. You can see what happens by running `await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()` in devtools console for the popup or in `chrome://serviceworker-internals` page.

Comment: Wow, so I can leave the manifest.json background blank, and handle my service worker only in popup.html, is that right?

Comment: Why not manifest.json?

Comment: Because I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging, the SDK automatic register `firebase-messaging-sw.js`, and there is no way to control this flow.